# Difference between WebUSB and WebSerial

Tags: usb, webusb

I am working on a project that involve accessing USB port using browser. I have seen WebUSB API and WebSerial API. Though I can't seem to get what is the difference between them? Can someone highlight the difference?

Comment: please specify your programming language.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two APIs is how they interface with the operating system to communicate with the device. WebUSB uses the platform-specific USB API while Web Serial uses the platform-specific serial API. This matters because USB is lower level than serial and because not every serial device is a USB device. With WebUSB you will be able to communicate with many different classes of USB device, including serial devices, but it requires the operating system allow the browser to "claim" the USB interface, which means there can't already be a USB device driver present. With Web Serial you will be able to communicate with USB serial devices, but also other types of serial devices such as Bluetooth as well as built-in RS-232 ports and other UARTs. The tradeoff you make with using Web Serial to connect to a USB device is that the operating system needs to have the correct USB serial driver installed so that the device is available through the platform-specific serial API used by the browser to implement Web Serial.

Answer (score 2):

**WebUSB** API is for providing access to USB (Universal Serial Bus) devices from web, But  **WebSerial** API is for providing access to serial ports complying with RS232 standards from web, like old printers port or old mouse port. RS232 is used on many devices like medical devices.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing, in my opinion, what you need to know is that webUSB works on android smartphones brouser and you can use USB-com adapters to take advantage of this.

The WebSerial does not work on smartphones. And therefore it is better to use WebUSB directly without a WebSerial gasket.

https://selevo.github.io/WebUsbSerialTerminal/

https://github.com/selevo/WebUsbSerialTerminal

from here we can conclude that if you use web USB, you will additionally realize the ability to use a million smartphones that are lying around in users’ bedside tables using them as a display, a touch panel, a mathematical processing device, and the device itself on a microcontroller can only perform real-time functions and other high-speed operations. Of course, you can also use a smartphone to change the firmware in the field. or in general any smartphone is much more compact and lighter than any laptop.

And of course, any smartphone is much more attractive in its electronic content than any single-board computer, since single-board computer like Raspberry Pi,
there is no display,no GSM,no batteries,no more sensors,no cameras
and much more. What is in case of smartphone