# Sending data between (Web) USB Host and ESP-32 S3

Tags: usb, esp32, webusb, web-serial-api

I'm looking for a simple example to exchange JSON ? data between a WebBrowser (USB Host) and an ESP-32-S3 from Lilygo. ChatGPT didn't help :-)

- HID Keyboard is very common library but there is no communication from JS to ESP-32
- WebHID can send "report" but no sample and very limited.
- [WebSerial and WebUSB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67580190/difference-between-webusb-and-webserial) are available on Chrome but no working sample

No, I don't want to setup a webserver on the ESP-32. I really want to send data through USB to a webpage or a chrome extension.

The only working code I get is :

```
  Vendor.onEvent(usbEventCallback);
  Vendor.onRequest(vendorRequestCallback);
  Vendor.begin();

  USB.onEvent(usbEventCallback);
  USB.webUSB(true);
  USB.webUSBURL("http://localhost/webusb");
  USB.begin();
```

and the implementation :

```
#include "USB.h"
#include "USBVendor.h"
USBVendor Vendor;

static void usbEventCallback(void* arg, esp_event_base_t event_base, int32_t event_id, void* event_data) {
  if (event_base == ARDUINO_USB_EVENTS) {
    arduino_usb_event_data_t * data = (arduino_usb_event_data_t*)event_data;
    switch (event_id) {
      case ARDUINO_USB_STARTED_EVENT:
        Serial.println("USB PLUGGED");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_STOPPED_EVENT:
        Serial.println("USB UNPLUGGED");
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_SUSPEND_EVENT:
        Serial.printf("USB SUSPENDED: remote_wakeup_en: %u\n", data->suspend.remote_wakeup_en);
        break;
      case ARDUINO_USB_RESUME_EVENT:
        Serial.println("USB RESUMED");
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  } else if (event_base == ARDUINO_USB_VENDOR_EVENTS) {
    arduino_usb_vendor_event_data_t * data = (arduino_usb_vendor_event_data_t*)event_data;
    switch (event_id) {
      case ARDUINO_USB_VENDOR_DATA_EVENT:
        Serial.printf("Vendor RX: len:%u\n", data->data.len);
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < data->data.len; i++) {
          Serial.write(Vendor.read());
        }
        Serial.println();
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

// CDC Control Requests
#define REQUEST_SET_LINE_CODING 0x20
#define REQUEST_GET_LINE_CODING 0x21
#define REQUEST_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE 0x22

//CDC Line Coding Control Request Structure
typedef struct __attribute__ ((packed)) {
  uint32_t bit_rate;
  uint8_t  stop_bits; //0: 1 stop bit, 1: 1.5 stop bits, 2: 2 stop bits
  uint8_t  parity;    //0: None, 1: Odd, 2: Even, 3: Mark, 4: Space
  uint8_t  data_bits; //5, 6, 7, 8 or 16
} request_line_coding_t;

static request_line_coding_t vendor_line_coding = {9600, 0, 0, 8};

// Bit 0:  DTR (Data Terminal Ready), Bit 1: RTS (Request to Send)
static uint8_t vendor_line_state = 0;

static const char * strRequestDirections[] = {"OUT", "IN"};
static const char * strRequestTypes[] = {"STANDARD", "CLASS", "VENDOR", "INVALID"};
static const char * strRequestRecipients[] = {"DEVICE", "INTERFACE", "ENDPOINT", "OTHER"};
static const char * strRequestStages[] = {"SETUP", "DATA", "ACK"};

uint8_t outBuffer[64];
bool vendorRequestCallback(uint8_t rhport, uint8_t requestStage, arduino_usb_control_request_t const * request) {
  Serial.printf("Vendor Request: Stage: %5s, Direction: %3s, Type: %8s, Recipient: %9s, bRequest: 0x%02x, wValue: 0x%04x, wIndex: %u, wLength: %u\n", 
    strRequestStages[requestStage],
    strRequestDirections[request->bmRequestDirection],
    strRequestTypes[request->bmRequestType],
    strRequestRecipients[request->bmRequestRecipient],
    request->bRequest, request->wValue, request->wIndex, request->wLength);
  bool result = false;

  if (request->bmRequestDirection == REQUEST_DIRECTION_OUT &&
      request->bmRequestType == REQUEST_TYPE_STANDARD &&
      request->bmRequestRecipient == REQUEST_RECIPIENT_INTERFACE &&
      request->bRequest == 0x0b
     ) {
    if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_SETUP) {
      // response with status OK
      result = Vendor.sendResponse(rhport, request);
    } else if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_DATA) {  
      // This is where the actual data is received  
        
      size_t len = Vendor.read(outBuffer, sizeof(outBuffer));  
      outBuffer[len] = 0; // Null-terminate the string  
      Serial.println((char*)outBuffer);
    } else {  
      result = true;
    }
  } else
    //Implement CDC Control Requests
    if (request->bmRequestType == REQUEST_TYPE_CLASS && request->bmRequestRecipient == REQUEST_RECIPIENT_DEVICE) {
      switch (request->bRequest) {

        case REQUEST_SET_LINE_CODING: //0x20
          // Accept only direction OUT with data size 7
          if (request->wLength != sizeof(request_line_coding_t) || request->bmRequestDirection != REQUEST_DIRECTION_OUT) {
            break;
          }
          if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_SETUP) {
            //Send the response in setup stage (it will write the data to vendor_line_coding in the DATA stage)
            result = Vendor.sendResponse(rhport, request, (void*) &vendor_line_coding, sizeof(request_line_coding_t));
          } else if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_ACK) {
            //In the ACK stage the response is complete
            Serial.printf("Vendor Line Coding: bit_rate: %u, data_bits: %u, stop_bits: %u, parity: %u\n", vendor_line_coding.bit_rate, vendor_line_coding.data_bits, vendor_line_coding.stop_bits, vendor_line_coding.parity);
          }
          result = true;
          break;

        case REQUEST_GET_LINE_CODING: //0x21
          // Accept only direction IN with data size 7
          if (request->wLength != sizeof(request_line_coding_t) || request->bmRequestDirection != REQUEST_DIRECTION_IN) {
            break;
          }
          if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_SETUP) {
            //Send the response in setup stage (it will write the data to vendor_line_coding in the DATA stage)
            result = Vendor.sendResponse(rhport, request, (void*) &vendor_line_coding, sizeof(request_line_coding_t));
          }
          result = true;
          break;

        case REQUEST_SET_CONTROL_LINE_STATE: //0x22
          // Accept only direction OUT with data size 0
          if (request->wLength != 0 || request->bmRequestDirection != REQUEST_DIRECTION_OUT) {
            break;
          }
          if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_SETUP) {
            //Send the response in setup stage
            vendor_line_state = request->wValue;
            result = Vendor.sendResponse(rhport, request);
          } else if (requestStage == REQUEST_STAGE_ACK) {
            //In the ACK stage the response is complete
            bool dtr = (vendor_line_state & 1) != 0;
            bool rts = (vendor_line_state & 2) != 0;
            Serial.printf("Vendor Line State: dtr: %u, rts: %u\n", dtr, rts);
          }
          result = true;
          break;

        default:
          // stall unknown request
          break;
      }
    }

  return result;
}
```

On the webpage side :

```
<html>
      <body>
          Hello
          <button id="connectButton">Connect</button>
          <script>

// Debug in Chrome: chrome://usb-internals/
let device;
const connectUSB = async () => {
    device = await navigator.usb.requestDevice({
        filters: [{  }]
    });

    await device.open(); // ouvre le périphérique  
    await device.selectConfiguration(1); // Sélectionne la configuration du périphérique  
    await device.releaseInterface(1);
    await device.claimInterface(1); // Réclame l'interface du périphérique  

    let encoder = new TextEncoder();  
    let data = encoder.encode("Hello ESP32"); // Convert string to bytes  
    device.transferOut(2, data); // Send data to endpoint 1  

    listen();
};

const listen = async () => {
    const result = await device.transferIn(3, 64);
    const decoder = new TextDecoder();
    const message = decoder.decode(result.data);
    console.log(message);
    listen();
};

document.getElementById("connectButton").onclick = connectUSB;

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Chrome browser see the ESP-32 in it's debug interface `chrome://usb-internals/` and there is 2 interfaces : HID and Special.

- device.claimInterface(0) is refused because Chrome protect HID device
- device.claimInterface(1) hang forever

So I don't know how to move forward. There is also a TinyUSB library but no working samples.

Comment: Serial will be simpler than USB or HID. Start here: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32s3/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html